Is there no longer a reason to clear storage variables? Refunds reduced post EIP-3529
Tried running a few crude tests of a contract like this:
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-3.0-only
    pragma solidity ^0.8.23;
    
    contract GasStorage {
    
        event GasLeft(uint256 gasLeft);
    
        uint256[] private arr;
// start with either uint256 max or zero
            uint256 val1 = 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff;
        
        constructor() { }
    
        function gasGasGas() external {
            emit GasLeft(gasleft());
    
    // imitate large gas usage
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                arr.push(0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff);
            }

// run four variations of storage change (skip or set to: zero, non-zero, max)

// skip do nothing
// set to: zero //     val1 = 0;
// set to: non-zero // val1 = 0x1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef;
// set to: max //      val1 = 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff;

            emit GasLeft(gasleft());
        }
    }

And what turned out is that there was never a case that the gas would yield a negative or at least 0 change only variations of usage.
--- (when val1 starts with 0x0) ---
(skip/no access)
total gas used: 246898
set to:
(non-zero) - total gas used: 269004 (+22106)
(max) - total gas used: 269004 (+22106)
(zero) - total gas used: 249104 (+2206)
--- (when val1 starts with max - 0xfffff... ) ---
(skip) - total gas used: 246898
set to:
(non-zero) - total gas used: 251904 (+5006)
(max) - total gas used: 249104 (+2206)
(zero) - total gas used: 251904 (+5006)
What absolutely baffled me mostly is that even when maxed value is zeroed it still actually costs gas. After reading docs and a few articles, the main goal of reduction was to stop gas tokens abusing storage, but now it's just not worth cleaning up at all.
Am I missing something? I understand these tests are very crude, but still nothing even close to 0 gas on clearing.

max - is a max uint256 value
non-zero - an arbitrary uint256 value, not zero, but not max.
test - ran on hardhat and hardhat network.
the addition values next to each case is gas comparison with doing nothing - skipping.
the arr iteration is to imitate large gas usage to allow for refunds to cover at least 20% of transaction (but I now doubt it was any need for it)

